# How to configure Vim backup directories

Tags: linux, vim, editor

I dislike Vim cluttering my working directory with backup and swap files, but I don't want to turn them off in case something crashes. I found that adding lines like:

```
set backupdir=./.backup
set directory=./.backup
```

in the Vim .vimrc configuration file tells Vim to put those files in a hidden directory. This is great except that if I do not manually create these hidden directories, it seems Vim does not create backup or swap files. I saw somewhere else lines like:

```
set backupdir=./.backup,/tmp,.
set directory=./.backup,/tmp,.
```

and thought that this would tell Vim to use the other locations, `/tmp` or `.`, if it cannot use `./.backup`, but Vim does not seem to do so.

How would I make Vim either:

1. create the needed `./backup` directory, or
2. use the working directory if the `./backup` directory does not exist?

Comment: nice post related to this: https://jdhao.github.io/2019/11/16/nvim_file_backup/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have these in my .vimrc to create a directory if it doesn't exist:

```
silent !mkdir ~/.vim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm sure you can modify to suit your needs, most likely:

```
silent !mkdir ./.backup > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I created a plugin to do this https://github.com/dezza/vimdirs.vim/blob/master/plugin/vimdirs.vim it's just a proof-of-concept but it is configurable.

Comment: use `mkdir -p` then you don't need to ignore errors ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add those to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set backup
if !isdirectory($HOME."/.vim/backupdir")
    silent! execute "!mkdir ~/.vim/backupdir"
endif
set backupdir=~/.vim/backupdir
"not generate .swap
set noswapfile
```

You'll find the backup in your directory `~/.vim/backupdir`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

`:h 'backupdir'` and `:h 'directory'` seem to indicate that your solution should work.

To check:

1. Add `set directory=./.backup,/tmp,.` to your `~/.vimrc`.
2. Close Vim.
3. Make sure `~/.backup` does not exist.
4. Reopen your `~/.vimrc` in Vim.
5. Check for `.vimrc.swp` in `/tmp`. (`ls -la /tmp | grep .vimrc.swp`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mkdir -p` which doesn't mind if the directory exists, and it can create paths so you can do stuff like:

```sh
mkdir -p .vim/backups
```

and it will always create the dir and never complain. No muss, no fuss.